# Second order Taylor expansion with Lagrangian form of the remainder

Tags: calculus, analysis, functional-analysis

I have a vector-valued smooth function $\boldsymbol{f}:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to use the second order Taylor expansion to bound

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(f_i(\boldsymbol{v} +\boldsymbol{h})-f_i(\boldsymbol{v})-\boldsymbol{h}^{T} \nabla f_i(\boldsymbol{v}))^2.$$

(It's squared euclidean norm.) Taylor's theorem for each coordinate implies

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(f_i(\boldsymbol{v} +\boldsymbol{h})-f_i(\boldsymbol{v})-\boldsymbol{h}^{T} \nabla f_i(\boldsymbol{v}))^2 \le \frac14 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sup_{\xi_i \in [v,v+h]}|\boldsymbol{h}^T\nabla^2 f_i(\boldsymbol{\xi_i})\boldsymbol{h}|^2.$$

But can we change the order of sum and supremum? In other words, can we write that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(f_i(\boldsymbol{v} +\boldsymbol{h})-f_i(\boldsymbol{v})-\boldsymbol{h}^{T} \nabla f_i(\boldsymbol{v}))^2 \le \frac14 \sup_{\xi \in [v,v+h]} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |\boldsymbol{h}^T\nabla^2 f_i(\boldsymbol{\xi})\boldsymbol{h}|^2.$$

Thanks!

Comment: The supremum of a sum is smaller than the sum of the supremums, and the inequality can be strict, so the short answer is: no. (However, there might be some other way to prove the inequality you want, I am checking)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, in general the inequality can be strict. But the inequality I want to prove follows (if I'm not wrong) from generalization of Taylor's theorem for multivariate and vector valued functions. So the point is to understand can we use Lagrangian form of the remainder in this generalized theorem or not.

Comment: No. In general, the Lagrangian form of the remainder fails for non-real-valued functions (i.e. complex-valued, vector-valued...). I am adding something to my answer to clarify this point. BTW: There is an inconsistency in your question. First, you say that "there exists $\xi\in[v, v+h]$ such that...". Then you take a supremum over $\xi$. There lies the cause of confusion.

Comment: Thanks! I've chacged the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the integral formulation of the remainder term (assume $f(0)=0$ just for the ease of typing)

$$
f(h)=Df(0)h+\int_0^1 D^2f(sh)(h,h)(1-s)\, ds,
$$
one gets the estimate you want:
$$
\left\lVert \int_0^1 D^2f(sh)(h,h)(1-s)\, ds\right\rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}\le \sup_{s\in[0,1]}\lVert D^2f(sh)(h,h) \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_0^1(1-s)\,ds$$
and $\int_0^1(1-s)\,ds=\frac{1}{2}.$

A comment on notation: $$Df(0)h=\sum_i\left(\sum_j \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}(0)\, h_j\right)e_i$$
$$
D^2f(p)(h,h)=\sum_k\left(\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i, \partial x_j}(p)\,h_ih_j\right) e_k, $$
where $e_k=(0,0,\ldots 1,\ldots, 0,0)$, the $1$ being in the $k$-th place.

**EDIT** Some more commentaries. If $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is real valued (and $f(0)=0$ for simplicity), then one can have the Lagrangian form of the remainder, i.e.

$$\tag{Lagr}\exists \xi \in (0,1)\quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad f(h)=Df(0)h +  \frac{1}{2}D^2f(\xi h)(h,h).$$

However, if $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is vector-valued, (Lagr) is not true. Take for example $m=2$, so that $f$ can be considered complex valued, and let $f(x)=e^{ix}-1$ for real $x$. Then (Lagr) becomes the identity
$$
\tag{!!} e^{ih}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i\xi h}h^2=1+ih, \qquad \text{some }\xi\in(0,1)$$
which is false. **EDIT** Explanation. By "(!!) is false" I mean in this case that there exists a neighborhood $(-\delta, \delta)$ of $0$ (which is the center of our Taylor expansion) such that for any $h\in(-\delta, \delta)$ there does not exist any $\xi\in(0,1)$ such that (Lagr) holds.

Proof: one simply expands exponentials to second order in $h$, using the Peano formulation of the remainder (which **is** true for vector-valued functions also). One gets 
$$
1+ih+(1+i)\frac{h^2}{2}+O(h^3)=1+ih, $$
which would imply $(1+i)h^2=O(h^3)$, which is false in a small enough neighborhood of $0$, because the right hand side is asymptotically smaller than the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain how you got the (!!) identity, please? I got a different one

Comment: @user44097: You are right, I made some computational mistakes. Fixing...

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you once again!